# Can not get example compiled with typedef in template class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have this example code:
    #include

```
template<class T>
class Class
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class<T> > Ref;
};

template<class T>
class Class2
{
public:
    Class<T>::Ref getAReference() {return Class<T>::Ref(new Class<T>);};
};
int main(){}
```

When I try to compile it, I get:

```
test.cpp:14: error: type ‘Class<T>’ is not derived from type ‘Class2<T>’
test.cpp:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘getAReference’
```

I do not get it, why does it not work? How do I make it work?

Comment: Are you showing the whole code? You are clearly lacking a `typename`, but if that is the error message you get from a missing `typename` with exactly the code you posted the compiler diagnostics are strange to say the least. The first line of error seems to point to a inheritance relation that is not present in the code.

Comment: I agree that this is strange, but I am showing the whole code and a typename made the message go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `Ref` is a type by using `typename` i.e.

```
typename Class<T>::Ref getAReference() {return Class<T>::Ref(new Class<T>);};
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123080/why-do-we-need-typename-here) discusses it further.