# Can't define templated types for my LruCache class

Tags: c++, linux, templates, gcc4

```
#include <map>
#include <list>

template < typename K, typename  V>
class LruCache
{
private:
    typedef std::pair< K, V > EntryPair;
    typedef std::list< EntryPair > CacheList;
    typedef std::map< K, CacheList::iterator > CacheMap;

public:
    LruCache(){}
    ~LruCache(){}
};
```

if I try simply

LruCache cache;

I get the following compilation error:

```
LruCache.h:17:46: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map’
LruCache.h:17:46: error:   expected a type, got ‘LruCache<K, V>::CacheList:: iterator’
LruCache.h:17:46: error: template argument 4 is invalid
```

However, if I define the class without template types. i.e.

```
class LruCache
{
private:
    typedef std::pair< int, int > EntryPair;
    typedef std::list< EntryPair > CacheList;
    typedef std::map< int, CacheList::iterator > CacheMap;

public:
    LruCache(){}
    ~LruCache(){}
};
```

It compiles just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typename` as:

```
typedef std::map< K,typename CacheList::iterator > CacheMap;
                   //^^^^^^
```

Its because `iterator` is a dependent name on the template argument. Its value *depends* on `CacheList` which in turn *depends* on the `T` which is in fact a template argument. That is why `typename` its needed here which tells the compiler that `iterator` is actually a nested ***type***, not `static` ***value***.

However, in the second case, its not a dependent name.

Read this detail explanation by Johannes:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Comment: The compiler does not know if CacheList::iterator is a type or a member. For instance, std::string::npos is a constant member, but std::vector::iterator is a type. Since `CacheList` relies on a template parameter (your K and V) the compiler guesses that CacheList::iterator is a member. Since you know it is a type, you must tell the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
typedef std::map< K, CacheList::iterator > CacheMap;
```

with this:

```
typedef std::map< K, typename CacheList::iterator > CacheMap;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123080/why-do-we-need-typename-here). Basically, the compiler doesn't know (without knowing the template arguments) whether `CacheList::iterator` is a type or a value until instantiation time, and it's forbidden from postponing the decision until then, so it assumes that it's a value and you have to give it a "hint" otherwise.