# A Few Template Questions (already solved... just want to know why)

Tags: c++, templates, stl

So, I'm developing a templated Vector class for an assignment and I came across a few issues that I solved by Googling, but I still want to know why what I was doing was wrong. First issue is that I had:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    ...
    template <typename T2>
    Vector(const Vector<T2> &other);
}

template <typename T, T2>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T2> &other)
{
    ...
}
```

this was giving me an "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration" in VS11. I fixed it by putting the template definitions on separate lines:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename T2>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T2> &other)
{
    ...
}
```

but I still don't know why this was needed. I know that the first definition is valid for functions/classes that use multiple templates in them, but why is it the case that the syntax changes when you mix a templated class with a templated member function?

My second question has to do with types inside of template classes. When writing the iterator I had functions such as:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    ...
    class iterator
    {
        ...
        iterator &operator++(void);
    }
}

template <typename T>
Vector<T>::iterator &Vector<T>::iterator::operator++(void)
{
    ...
}
```

which gave me "dependent name is not a type" and I later found out that I needed to add "typename" in front:

```
template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator &Vector<T>::iterator::operator++(void)
{
    ...
}
```

After Googling the warning number (which resulted in an error), I realized why the error exists, but it isn't too obvious why the compiler doesn't know that `Vector<T>::iterator` is a type. I mean, it has the definition of the class, so...

Anyway, thanks for clarifying these few things for me!

Comment: Can I suggest that you drop the second part of the question and take [this existing post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123080/why-do-we-need-typename-here) as an answer? (The first part can remain of course -- having just one question per post is much better anyway.)

Comment: Who downvoted this? OP has a legit question about template syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
template <typename T2>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T2> &other)
{
```

Is also valid to be written as

```
template <typename T> template <typename T2>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T2> &other)
{
```

You just need (?) to write it out as two sets, since they are after all two sets of parameters - first one is for the class, second one for the function.

`typename` for dependant types and related rules (`this` for template base class members and `template` for template member functions(?) ) have to do with something called [**"Two Phase Lookup"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed). This is however badly implemented (as in not) on MSVC++, so it may not throw as many errors as a conforming implementation might.

More info - http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html
http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates/

Comment: To be clear (in case it's not), it's because OP is defining a templated member of a template: template <typename T> refers to class and template<typename T2> refers to the member of the class. (I'm pretty sure OP knows that extra whitespace is not significant in C++ :D)

Comment: @StephenLin Thats what I mention isnt it? The OP specifically mentions "seperate lines", which is what I wanted to correct

Comment: eg: if Vector were a template taking two template parameters with a non-templated constructor, then `template<typename T, typename T2> Vector<T1, T2>::Vector(...)` would be correct: most of the time you define template member functions inline with the class definition anyway so you never come across this.

Comment: Yeah but the main issue is why it's two separate templates not that it's on two different lines, as far as I can tell. Just wanted to make it clearer.

Comment: Oh snap, I made a typo. My original implementation was with `template <typename T, typename T2>` <- separated by a comma

Comment: Well, now I'm not sure what you're asking about. Anyway, it's definitely two templates...one template defined inside another, which is distinct from one template having two parameters.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help though. It was informative. Also, just for a little clarification: I was getting an error for the second part because the compiler didn't know the type during the first phase? That's kind of silly IMO since it should at least know that iterator is defined as a class.

Comment: (so `template<typename T, typename T2> Vector::Vector<T1, T2>(...)` would work if Vector were non-templated but its constructor was templated on two parameters)

Comment: @StephenLin I was wondering why/in what situations you needed to separate template definitions (since I know that it is usually done with `template <typename T1, typename T2, ...>` though I think I understand the difference now

Comment: w.r.t. to `typename`: it's not always that easy. Anyway, `typename` was not required for dependent names originally and compilers got along fine usually, but the problem is a template basically isn't fully evaluated until its instantiated and template arguments are substituted so it made it hard for the compiler to verify anything about the template without knowing ahead of time what's supposed to be a type and what isn't. With `typename`, the compiler can at least do some minimal verification that a template is well-formed before instantiation.