# resolve C++ class template errors on my list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, c++11

I have create this squareList class I when I compile it it give me to many errors I don't know can someone help me to resolve those error 
update: I comment all my code after ~square_list(){} and every error pinpoint to        list data;

```
///#include "LinkedList.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>


template <typename T_>

class square_list
{

    typedef T_              value_type;
    typedef std::size_t     size_type;
    typedef T_ &            reference;
    typedef T_ const &      const_reference;
    typedef T_ *            pointer;
    typedef T_ const *      const_pointer;
    typedef T_ *            iterator;
    typedef T_ const *      const_iterator;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t  difference_type;

    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;



     //for header vector<pair<itr,unsindINT) header
    list<T_> data;





    square_list() {}
    ~square_list(){}

 //   bool empty(){
    //  if(this->begin() == nullptr && this->end() == nullptr)
    //      return 1;
    //  else
    //      return 0;
    //}

    //list<value_type>::iterator    begin() {
    //  return data.begin(); 
    //}
    //list<value_type>::iterator    end() { 
    //  return data.end(); 
    //}
};
```

> Error 1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 10  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 13  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 16  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 19  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 22  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 25  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 28  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 31  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 34  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 37  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 40  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 43  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 46  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   Error 3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Error  6   error
>   C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Error  9   error C2238:
>   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  Error  12  error C2238: unexpected
>   token(s) preceding ';'     Error  15  error C2238: unexpected token(s)
>   preceding ';'  Error  18  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding
>   ';'    Error  21  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 24  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 27  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 30  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 33  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 36  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 39  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 42  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 45  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error 48  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Error  2   error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int    Error  5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Error  8   error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int    Error  11  error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Error  14  error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int    Error  17  error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Error  20  error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int    Error  23  error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Error  26  error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int    Error  29  error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Error  32  error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int    Error  35  error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Error  38  error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int    Error  41  error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Error  44  error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int    Error  47  error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: The only issue I see is `list<T> data` which should be `list<T> data`. Other than that I see no other problem. Are you sure this code reproduces the errors shown?

Comment: yes it reproduces and no use?

Comment: since you typedef T_ as value_type you should use value_type instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the compiler error is caused by the private construtor, this piece of code can compiler, hope it will help,

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

#define nullptr NULL
template <typename T_>
class square_list
{
public:
    typedef T_              value_type;
    typedef std::size_t     size_type;
    typedef T_ &            reference;
    typedef T_ const &      const_reference;
    typedef T_ *            pointer;
    typedef T_ const *      const_pointer;
    typedef T_ *            iterator;
    typedef T_ const *      const_iterator;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t  difference_type;

    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;



     //for header vector<pair<itr,unsindINT) header
    list<value_type> data;


    square_list() {}
    ~square_list(){}

    bool empty(){
        if(this->begin() == nullptr && this->end() == nullptr)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    /*list<T_>::iterator  begin() {
        return data.begin();
    }
    list<T_>::iterator  end() {
        return data.end();
    }*/
};


int main()
{
    square_list<int> sq_list;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: btw, if you want begin() and end() function compile, typename should be used before the return value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123080/why-do-we-need-typename-here

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is this line

```
list<T> data<T>;
```

it should be

```
list<T> data;
```

Those template arguments are unnecessary and syntactically invalid. Also, you haven't defined the template argument `T`. Did you mean `T_` (or `value_type` rather)?

Also, you need `typename` in return types of your `begin()` and `end()` methods as `value_type` is a dependent type:

```
typename list<value_type>::iterator  begin();
typename list<value_type>::iterator  end();
```

You can even take advantage of return type deduction:

```
auto begin() -> decltype(data.begin());
auto end()   -> decltype(data.end());
```

Comment: can you see the update because I comment all stuff after ~square_list(){}

Comment: no I have boost test unit act as my main also many error come from list<T> data; after i updated with you Answer  line i don't know what is the problem i

Answer (score 0):

Your template parameter is `T_`, but you are referring to something called `T` which is undefined.  Try changing

```
list<T> data<T>;
```

to

```
list<T_> data;
```

Also, try commenting out everything inside the class declaration and compiling.  Then uncomment one line at a time and deal with any errors that appear after adding each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
list<value_type> data;
```

The code's problem is lack of `std::` as follows:

```
std::list<value_type> data;
```

You also write `using namespace std;` before the class definition.