# Why the default value is needed for `std::enable_if`?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Why I have to use the default value (`::type = 0`) in this `std::enable_if` usage?

I see examples, where it works without it. for example https://foonathan.net/blog/2015/11/30/overload-resolution-4.html

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type = 0>
void do_stuff(T t) {
    std::cout << "do_stuff integral\n";
}

template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type = 0>
void do_stuff(T t) {
    std::cout << "do_stuff class\n";
}

int main()
{
    do_stuff(32);
    return 0;
}
```

I got error message:

```
temp.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
temp.cpp:18:13: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
```

It should be deduced to

```
template <template T, int>
void do_stuff(T t)
```

which is a valid code.
What I'm doing wrong? (*gcc* version *7.4.0*)

Comment: In the example you cite, the invocation of `enable_if` **is** the default argument. It looks like this: `typename = std::enable_if<...>::type`. It's the template type parameter (with its name omitted) given a default value. In your code, you have a non-type template parameter of type `std::enable_if<...>::type`, with no way to deduce it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When I do this I get: temp.cpp:13:6: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T, class> void do_stuff(T)’
 void do_stuff(T t) {
      ^~~~~~~~
temp.cpp:7:6: note: ‘template<class T, class> void do_stuff(T)’ previously declared here
 void do_stuff(T t) {

Comment: The example in the article doesn't compile either. Probably time to look for a better article.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. It's Jonathan Müller's post (https://twitter.com/foonathan). It should work :)

Comment: Well, maybe it should, but [it does not](https://rextester.com/VARD8825)

Comment: @DanielLangr. Yes, this is the working example, I'm asking why ::type = 0 has to be there? Try to remove it.

Comment: @MiCha I see, misinterpreted your question (it would be better to post a code that produces the error). Anyway, AnT's answer explains the problem.

Comment: In the second overload for class-type `T`, note the `= 0` default template argument won't compile if class `T` can't be copy-initialized from a `0`. This is why you'll see some code use instead `template <`...`, typename std::enable_if<` _expr_ `>::type* = nullptr>`.  In that usage, the type resulting from `enable_if` is `void` if _expr_ is true, so the last template parameter type is always `void*` no matter what the other template parameter(s) are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler clearly told you what the problem is: in your template declaration you specified an extra template non-type parameter that cannot be deduced. How do you expect the compiler to deduce a proper value for that non-type parameter? From what?

This is exactly why the above technique for using `std::enable_if` requires a default argument. This is a dummy parameter, so the default argument value does not matter (`0` is a natural choice).

You can reduce your example to a mere

```
template <typename T, T x> 
void foo(T t) {}

int main()
{
  foo(42);
}
```

Producing

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo(int)'
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'x'
```

The compiler can deduce what `T` is (`T == int`), but there's no way for the compiler to deduce the argument for `x`.

Your code is exactly the same, except that your second template parameter is left unnamed (no need to give a name to a dummy parameter).

---

Judging by your comments, you seem to be confused by the presence of keyword `typename` in the declaration of the second parameter in your code, which makes you believe that the second parameter is also a **type** parameter. The latter is not true.

Note, that in the second parameter's declaration keyword `typename` is used in *a completely different role*. This keyword simply disambiguates the semantics of

```
std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type
```

It tells the compiler that nested name `type` actually represents a name of a *type*, not of something else. (You can read about this usage of `typename` here: [Why do we need typename here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123080/why-do-we-need-typename-here) and [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords))

This usage of `typename` does not turn the second parameter of your template into a **type** parameter. The second parameter of your template is still a **non-type** parameter.

Here's another simplified example that illustrates what happens in your code

```
struct S { typedef int nested_type; };

template <typename T, typename T::nested_type x>
void bar(T t)
{}

int main()
{
  S s;
  bar<S, 42>(s);
}
```

Note that even though the declaration of the second parameter begins with a `typename`, it still declares a non-type parameter.

Comment: it seems that you are right. I'm still missing there something. My understanding is that if compiler deduces the first T to int, then also the second T is int, so -> x is int. What do you mean by "arguments for x?", type ? Thx for clarification

Comment: @MiCha: You seem to be missing the fact that in both cases the first template parameter is a **type** parameter, while the second is a **non-type** parameter (a "value" parameter). In my example parameter `T` stands for `int`, but `x` does not stand for `int`. `x` is a **value** parameter, it stands for **some value** of type `int`. What value is the compiler supposed to use? The compiler does not know.

Comment: @ AnT Yes, you are right, but that's the **difference** between your and my example. In my case also the second template parameter is type (keyword typename) and the enable_if::type is alias for T. So if T is int then ::type is int, so why the type parameter needs also the **default value**? Thx

Comment: @MiCha: No, no, no, no, no. Your example is exactly the same as mine. You simply misinterpreted the meaning of the word `typename` in the second parameter. No, it **does not** mean that this is a type parameter. Your second parameter is a value parameter, just like mine. See the updated answer.

Comment: That's it! Thank you !

Comment: @MiCha As an aside, avoid using a dummy-parameter when you can use the return-type, to avoid pushing it into the decorated name, in case that ends up in a symbole-table.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error; anyway I get an error calling `do_stuff()` with a class. By example

```
do_stuff(std::string{"abc"})
```

This is because `do_stuff()` become `do_stuff<std::string, std::string = 0>()` and a template value can't be of type `std::string` (and not with default value zero).

Suggestion: rewrite your functions imposing `int` as type for the value in second position

```
template <typename T, // .....................................VVV  int, not T
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void do_stuff(T t) {
    std::cout << "do_stuff integral\n";
}

template <typename T, // ..................................VVV  int, not T
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void do_stuff(T t) {
    std::cout << "do_stuff class\n";
}
```

This way, calling `do_stuff(std::string{"abc"})`, you enable `do_stuff<std::string, int = 0>()` that is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, the best is: `template <typename T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>`. The question is, why this nullptr have to be there ?

Comment: @MiCha Well, where else is the value of this non-type template parameter supposed to come from? You basically have `template <typename T, void* x> void do_stuff(T);` - the compiler needs the value for `x`

Comment: @MiCha - There is no needs of use `T` (directly or as a pointer); `int = 0` works perfectly. Anyway, the `= nullptr` (or `= 0`, in my example) is necessary to avoid to explicit it; otherwise you have to call `do_stuff<int, nullptr>(42)` instead of `do_stuff(42);`.