# Error defining const static member of class if the class has template

Tags: c++, templates, declaration

I have the following code in a `.h` file:

```
class Test1 {
    struct A1 {
        int x;
    };
    static const A1 a1;
};

template <class T>
class Test2 {
    struct A2 {
        int x;
    };
    static const A2 a2;
};
```

and I define values for both `a1` and `a2` in a `.cpp` file:

```
const Test1::A1 Test1::a1 = { 5 };

template<class T>
const Test2<T>::A2 Test2<T>::a2 = { 5 };
```

The odd thing is that for `Test1` everything works, but for `Test2` I get the following error in the last line of the `.cpp` file:

`Error  C2061   syntax error: identifier 'A2'`

The only difference between `Test1` and `Test2` is that `Test2` has a template. Why is this a problem, and how can I fix it? Also, this works as well:

`test.h`

```
struct A3 {
    int x;
};
template <class T>
class Test3 {
    static const A3 a3;
};
```

`test.cpp`

```
template<class T>
const A3 Test3<T>::a3 = { 5 };
```

So the problem is with using a struct defined in a templated class, but I can't find out what exactly is the problem.

(I'm compiling with c++14.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is suggested by a compiler, just be more careful in reading the compiler messages.

```
<source>(17): warning C4346: 'A2': dependent name is not a type
<source>(17): note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
<source>(17): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'A2'
<source>(17): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
<source>(17): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Or

```
<source>:17:7: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'Test2<T>::A2'
const Test2<T>::A2 Test2<T>::a2 = { 5 };
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      typename 
1 error generated.
```

That means the correct code:

```
template<class T>
const typename Test2<T>::A2 Test2<T>::a2 = { 5 };
```

Read more: [Why do we need typename here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123080/why-do-we-need-typename-here).