# C++ iterator for map derived class

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a class that internally has an instance of map:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class my_map {
    private:
        std::map<K, V> mmap;
```

Internally to the class I need to create an iterator for templated types, how can I do this?

Comment: You want an internal variable that is an iterator to the contained map?

Comment: Yes, in my internal methods I want to create an interator to the map using the types K,V ?

Comment: the question is unclear. whats the problem? `mmap.begin()` is an iterator, `mmap.end()` another one

Comment: Declare a member variable like this: `decltype(mmap.begin()) myIterator;` ??

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, what's unclear, the class can be declared with any types for K or V and internally I want to create iterators using those.

Comment: its not clear what problem you encountered. As I wrote, `mmap.begin()` is an iterator, there you go...

Comment: `std::map<K,V>::iterator` is the type of the iterator

Comment: @AdrianMole, I want to assign this to the result of mmap.find(value);

Comment: `auto it = mmap.find(value)` ? Please include the code with the issue in the question

Comment: You want to use it in a local (member) function, then `auto myIt = mmap.find(value);`. Still not really clear what you want.

Comment: seems like the issue is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123080/why-do-we-need-typename-here. If you have code that causes a compiler error, you better show the code, see [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid confusion with `typename` keyword. I suggest to do the following

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class my_map {
private:
    std::map<K, V> mmap;
public:
    typedef typename std::map<K, V>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::map<K, V>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() {return mmap.begin();}
    const_iterator begin() const {return mmap.begin();}
    .
    .
    .
};
```

You can now use it as `my_map<K, V>::iterator` or `my_map<K, V>::const_iterator`.

Comment: Still get missing 'typename' prior to dependant type name 'std::map<K, V>::iterator' and again on the const_iterator.

Comment: Just edited. Forgot to add the keyword in class.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map<K, V>::iterator`

see member types of [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: Tried that before I created this post, won't compile, I get: 'missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::map<K,V>::iterator'

Comment: @SPlatten thats because its a dependent type, you need to add `typename` before.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, tried, won't compile.